# Why my custom template for a static front page is not shown?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to set a custom static front page for my Wordpress, with a custom template.

I create `landingpage.php` in `wp-content/themes/my_theme` and I create a new page in my wordpress admin with LandingPage model selected.

If I go to `my_website.com/landing-page/` my custom page works and 'Hello World!' appears, but if I set my custom page as a static front page and go to `my_website.com/` my 'Hello World!' message doesn't display.

My `landingpage.php` code:

```
<?php /* Template Name: LandingPage */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'page' );
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
            endwhile;
            ?>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`front-page.php` has precedence over your custom template.

When that post is viewed as a **page** (e.g. by using its permalink url, **/landing-page/**), the custom template you defined (`landingpage.php`) will be used.

But if the same page is accessed as a front-page, the template for static front page is used, and that one is called `front-page.php` (if it exists).

Either delete your `front-page.php` template, or modify it so it mimics the behavior your wanted in `landingpage.php`.

The corollary for this is that for a static front page, you don't need to assign a specific custom template if you have a `front-page.php` template. You can use any page whatsoever, and that template will apply.

Answer (score 1):

You should name your file as `front-page.php` instead, wordpress will automatically detect that and will load that instead. 
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/